# Excel: Compare 2 columns and pull missing data into 3rd column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is the situation:

Column A: Some employees (Partial List)

Column E: All employees (Complete List)

I need Column C to be populated with all other employees not in Column A (Column A compared to Column E to pull data into Column C that is not in Column A).

I have tried IF, VLOOKUP functions and have come close but don't want any blank cells in Column C.

I would prefer a VBA code (as column A and C are linked to an external datasource) and are populated using VBA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm slow at developing macros, so I'm not going to write this as an answer. A good approach will involve combining these two ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268383/put-entire-column-each-value-in-column-in-an-array#21269273
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457432/compare-2-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with formulas (and a helper column)

In column `F` type the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,E2)
```

And populate down

In `C2` type the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E$2:E$10,MATCH(0,F$2:F$10,0)),"")
```

in `C3` type the following array formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(E$2:E$10,MATCH(1,(F$2:F$10=0)*(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,E$2:E$10)=0),0)),"")}
```

(type  and not just )

Then populate down